# System File Corruption causing Freezing a KSOD

Tags: windows-server-2012, terminal-server, windows-update, corruption, dism

At present we are having some difficulties with one of our Terminal Servers. It is a VM Server 2012 (64bit)

What is happening at the moment is that random applications (IE, Chrome, Notepad, Word, Outlook, Excel, Explorer) will start becoming unresponsive (it is not "Not Responding" you are unable to click, move, or close the window) and this is happening to all users who use the Terminal Server (at different times) and the programs do *not* eventually start responding again they need to be force closed.

At first we attempted

"*SFC /Scannow*"

which resulted

"*windows resource protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them... The system file repair changes will take effect after the next reboot*"

After the next reboot, we had a KSOD (Black Screen of Death) after the Windows Logo

[image: KSOD]

We then restored a checkpoint prior to the SFC.

The DISM log shows:

*CBS Manifest Corruption: 67*
*CBS Metadata Corruption: 14*

I then attempted:

*DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth* which i got the error message:

*Error: 0x800f0906 The source files could not be downloaded..*

Then tried

*dism /mount-wim /wimfile:D:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /MountDir:c:\DISM*
and

*Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:c:\DISM\Windows /LimitAccess*

Which gave me the error:

*Error: 0x800f081f The source files could not be found..*

Windows updates also wont run, just sitting at 0%

I am convinced that it is file corruption causing the freezing, and windows updates issues. Does anyone have any idea what could be done to repair the corruption? Ideally, i would rather not do a reinstall.

Cheers!

Comment: look in the CBS.log which files are corrupted ad can't be repaired.

Comment: I have looked through and manually repaired the files except for three that i can't find downloads for "KB2887535 KB2887536 KB2887537" In addition to this, i noticed that there are a lot of missing updates from 'view installed updates'

Comment: all 3 are related to WindowsUpdate CLient Updates, but I can only find the MSU files fro the 1st update.